# Tricky Combinations Splitting Problem - Real World

Tags: permutations, contest-math, combinations, computer-science

Find out the Number of Combinations if we split the number - **232345** in 3 sections such that the order is maintained always but each section can have : **Min 1** and **Max 3** numbers. Examples:

- 2. 32  . 345
- 2. 323 . 45
- 23. 2  . 345
- 23. 23 . 45
- 23. 234. 5
- 232. 34. 5
- 232. 3. 45

How can we find out the no of Combinations **without writing each combination Manually**. What will be the **Algorithm** to split the Numbers to generate a computer Program to find all combinations as well?


(this Algorithm will be used to Determine Valid Ip Addresses)

Comment: Your last sentence worries me. Not all quadruples of one to three digit numbers are valid IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to solving $a+b+c=6$, where $1 \leq a,b,c \leq 3$.

Let $a=a’+1$, $b=b’+1$, $c=c’+1$. We’re solving $a’+b’+c’=3$, where $0\leq a’,b’,c’ \leq 2$.

The no. of the possible solutions is:

$$\binom{3+2}{2}-3=7$$

where we minus $3$ because none of $a’,b’,c’$ can be $3$. Unfortunately, it seems like I have to leave your question about **Algorithm** to someone else.